# How can I paste a string using dmlwrite?

Tags: matlab

I have values of this kind that come from a loop and I want to store in a csv file. Other column are numeric.

```
k = 1
accumStartTime = 7.3474e+05
xy  = datestr(accumStartTime);
dlmwrite('test.csv', [k, xy], '-append', 'precision', '%.6f', 'delimiter', ',');
```

But this gives me garbled output as the string xy is getting divided by commas.

How can fix it?

Comment: I don't think `dlmwrite` can handle mix of numeric and strings. You'll have to use `fprintf` to write such a line.

Comment: You can use xlswrite if you want to mix of numeric and strings too.

Comment: @Hoki Thanks. Any examples?

Comment: @oro777 The actual file is going to have 10,000+ rows. Is that OK with xlswrite?

Comment: @maximusdooku I don't think there are any limitations. If the output file was an XLS file, there would be a row limitation but here you work with a CSV file which is a text based file so it should be OK.